# Multiple div selection onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs with their id's, and onclick i store the id of the div in an input value, but it only takes one id, i want to have multiple selection and store all the selected div id's in the same input, here is my code:

```js
  function storeId (el) {
     $('input').val(el.id);
  }
```

```css
div{
background-color:red;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1" onclick="storeId(this);">
</div>

<div id="div-2" onclick="storeId(this);">
</div>

<div id="div-3" onclick="storeId(this);">
</div>

<div id="div-4" onclick="storeId(this);">
</div>

<input>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the input's value directly, store the `id` in an array and then upon each click, update the input with the array's contents.

Also, don't use inline HTML event attributes. There are **[many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991)** not to use this ancient technique that just will not die.

```js
let ids = [];
$("div").on("click", function(){
  // If the id is not already in the array, add it. If it is, remove it
  ids.indexOf(this.id) === -1 ? ids.push(this.id) : ids.splice(ids.indexOf(this.id),1);
  $('input').val(ids.join(", ")); // populate the input with the array items separated with a comma
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color:red;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display:inline-block; /* Just for the SO space */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-1"></div>
<div id="div-2"></div>
<div id="div-3"></div>
<div id="div-4"></div>

<input>
```

Comment: Thank you, but here the user can select the same div more than once so it stores the id more than once, and how can i unselect the div when clicking on it again please?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options based on your requirements:

1. Append newly clicked id's to the existing value of your input.
2. Push newly clicked id's into an array which is used to build the value of your input.

### Option 1

```
function storeId (el) {
   var currentValue = $('input').val();
   $('input').val(currentValue + ', ' + el.id);
}
```

(Or with newer syntax)

```
function storeId (el) {
   const currentValue = $('input').val();
   $('input').val(`${currentValue}, ${el.id}`);
}
```

### Option 2

```
var storedIds = [];
function storeId (el) {
   var index = storedIds.indexOf(el.id);
   if (index === -1) {
      storedIds.push(el.id);
   } else {
      storedIds.splice(index, 1);
   }

   $('input').val(storedIds.join(', '));
}
```

Edit: Only the array example above checks if the id being stored has already been stored or not.

Answer (score -1):

Please try it:

```
    function storeId (el) {
        if ($('input').val().indexOf(el.id) >= 0){
            $('input').val($('input').val().replace(el.id + ",", ""));
            return
        }
        $('input').val($('input').val() + el.id + ",");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great! but one more thing, how can i unselect the div and remove it's value on second click?